# pug- do an action based on if an element exits in a variable

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

I am using Express js to build a web app. I use an API to get some data and then send it to a pug file in the below format.

```
res.render('native.pug', {product_name: body.products, cart_items:body.cart, item_count:body.count, amount: body.totalAmount, sid: sess.id});
```

body is a json object.

I get id field(along with other fields) in both body.products and body.cart

body.products consists a list of all the products and their details

body.cart consists of details of all the products the user added to the cart.

Now, in the native.pug file, I wish to display different texts, based on if a particular id from body.products is present or not in body.cart

Here is what I tried

```
each prod in product_name
    if prod.id in cart_items.id
        button Add to Cart
    else
        button abc
```

I get the following error

```
Add to Cart 23| else 24| button abc Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '590' in undefined
```

Where am I going wrong exactly?

**EDIT**: indentation

Comment: You have no variable `prod`. Also it sounds like `cart_items` is probably an array, so it wouldn't have an `id` property.

Comment: prod is the variable for each element in product_items.. I'll update that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
if (cart_items.indexOf(prod.id) > -1)
    button Add to Cart
else
    button abc
```

This assumes that

1. `prod` is an object with an `id` property
2. `cart_items` is an array of `id`s

Comment: "cart_items.includes is not a function" is the error that I get

Comment: @krishna Try changing the if condition to `if (cart_items.indexOf(prod.id) !==  -1)`

Comment: @krishna any luck?

Comment: that worked just like I wanted... thanks a lot @MohitBhardwaj

Comment: could you change the cart_items.includes to cart_items.indexOf() @Aron

Comment: @Aron `includes` is a newer method and may not be available on older versions. So, you should add  alternate solution using `indexOf`. It will make your answer more useful, as some user may not have versions that support `includes`.

Comment: What would I do if i needed to match different fields? like let's say i wanna match field abc from cart_itesm to field id in prod?

Comment: @krishna as in each `cart_item` in `cart_items` is an object with an `abc` property?